# onClick does no fire reactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have been trying to fix the problem by searching for onClick not firing problem, but alas, noone seemed to have a proper solution.

For this project, I have recently learned ReactJs to integrate it within AngularJS to replace slow ng-repeat in Angular.

The problem I have right now is that onClick does not call the updateOrders function when clicking on a rendered `<tr>`. Through my testing I have confirmed that the problem does not lie in the click handler.

Through my research, I have found out that people have the same problem when using .map function to generate an array. While I have manually done so, the problem remains.

I hope the community would be helpful in pointing out what I am doing wrong.

Thank you very much!

```
/*Click handler*/ 


function updateOrders(reactComponent, ordPrice, ordAmt) {
      var scope = reactComponent.scope.$root;
      scope.updateOrderInputS(ordPrice,ordAmt)

    }

/*Component*/

var ReactCSSTransitionGroup = React.addons.CSSTransitionGroup;
var OrderBook = React.createClass({


  render: function() {
    var reactComponent = this.props;
    var asks = this.props.data.asks;
    var bids = this.props.data.bids;
    var asksRows = [];
    var bidsRows = [];
    var spread = Number(asks[asks.length-1].price - bids[0].price);
    spread = spread.toFixed(2);

    //creating array of react elements to return
    for (var i = 0; i < asks.length; i++) {
      var ask = asks[i];
      asksRows.push(
        React.createElement(
          "tr",
          { "className": "trade", "key": i, "onClick": updateOrders(reactComponent, ask.price, ask.amount) },
          //{ "className": "trade", "key": i },
          React.createElement(
                    "td",
                    null,
                    Number(ask.amount).toFixed(2)
          ),
          React.createElement(
                    "td",
                    { style: {color: "#FF6939"} },
                    '$'+ Number(ask.price).toFixed(2)
          )
        )
      )
    };

    for (var i = 0; i < bids.length; i++) {
      var bid = bids[i];
      bidsRows.push(
        React.createElement(
          "tr",
          { "className": "trade", "key": i*Math.PI, "onClick": updateOrders(reactComponent,bid.price, bid.amount) },
          //{ "className": "trade", "key": i*Math.PI},
          React.createElement(
                    "td",
                    null,
                    Number(bid.amount).toFixed(2)
          ),
          React.createElement(
                    "td",
                    { style: {color: "#50b949"} },
                    '$'+ Number(bid.price).toFixed(2)
          )
        )
      )
    };

    return (
      React.createElement(
        "div",
        null,
        React.createElement(
          "div",
          { "className": "row section-head" },
          React.createElement(
            "h5",
            null,
            "DEPTH:",
            React.createElement("span", { id: "mktDptProd", style:{color:"white" }})
          )
        ),
        React.createElement(
          "table",
          { "className": "table scroll table-condensed", style:{textAlign:"center"} },
          React.createElement(
            "thead",
            null,
            React.createElement(
              "tr",
              null,
              React.createElement(
                "th",
                null,
                "SIZE"
              ),
              React.createElement(
                "th",
                null,
                "PRICE"
              )
            )
          ),
          React.createElement(
            "tbody",
            { id: "MDtable", style: {height:"800px"} },
            asksRows,
            React.createElement(
              "tr",
              { style: {borderTop: "1px solid #4B555C", borderBottom: "1px solid #4B555C", display:"block"} },
              React.createElement(
                "td",
                null,
                "Spread:"
              ),
              React.createElement(
                "td",
                null,
                spread
              )
            ),
            bidsRows
          )
        )
      )
  );
  }
});
```

Comment: a jsx version would be more readable, do you have such?

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is really painful to read this... but this might be the problem.
In line #25 and #46, you don't actually pass the function but you call (execute) it. The correct way would be to change updateOrders. Basically, you need to return a function which will be called when the element is clicked.

```
function updateOrders(reactComponent, ordPrice, ordAmt) {
  return function(e) {
    var scope = reactComponent.scope.$root;
    scope.updateOrderInputS(ordPrice,ordAmt)
  }
}
```

Comment: I apologise for readability, but i do not have a jsx version of it. I have tried to ifx the code as suggested but it still does not work as intended

Comment: Did the inner function returned by `updateOrders` get executed?

Comment: At some reloads, it gets executed only once after 1 click. Then it stops working (clicking on other <tr> does not trigger updateOrders)

Comment: Hmm, it works for me here https://jsfiddle.net/Lp7hgu41/ Each click executes the function returned by updateOrders

Comment: Thank you very much for the feedback. I see the problem is not in the react component then

Comment: You are welcome. One piece of advice, you shouldn't mix React and Angular, it will get nasty really soon. Instead, you can optimize `ng-repeat` by having smaller list (pagination for instance) or check the digest process to make sure that `ng-repeat` is not called too many times